# Fixing the xrange of one plot to another

Tags: plot, gnuplot

I want to plot a multiplot in gnuplot with two plots. One plot on top of another. The underlying data files for both plots will be constantly changing and every 5 seconds, both plots will be refreshed.

Is there a way to ensure that the xrange of the bottom plot always stays the same as the xrange of the top plot? The top plot will be auto scaled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gnuplot has `set xrange writeback | restore` for this. As example consider

```
set xrange [-10:10]

set multiplot layout 1,2

set yrange [] writeback
plot sin(x)

set yrange restore
replot x/2
unset multiplot
```

That uses the autoscale limits of the first plot for the second plot. In your case use of course `set xrange [] writeback` ... `set xrange [] restore`.